# Cannot install app: "Sorry, only tenant administrators can add or give access to this app."

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

For adding an app, that has Search query permission, to a site collection as site owner I get the following message:

[image]

Well, Search works on tenant level, so to add the app to a site collection I need to do that as tenant admin. I understand that. But if I deploy the app to the app catalog I think that should be sufficient to allow the site administrators install the app. Unfortunately this did not seem to be so. So my question is, is there a workaround to fix this issue in SharePoint Online till Microsoft comes with a solution? In SharePoint On Premise someone suggested this workaround: [SharePoint 2013 Apps - Tenant Admin Bug und Workaround](http://www.bigdata-unleashed.com/20131128/sharepoint-2013-apps-tenant-admin-bug-und-workaround)

Comment: what plan you have whether you are on a P-plan or E-Plan?

Comment: A trial E Plan!

Comment: i think the app you are trying to install is required Tenant Scope permission? Can you try to install any other application and see if that works.

Comment: Also check this technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn609806.aspx

Comment: @Waqas Sarwar MCSE, related to "SharePoint Online Self-Service Tenant Scoped App Deployment Guide" you suggested above, when I go to Site Settings on the App Catalog, I can't see Cross Site App Permission under Users and Permissions!!

Comment: You may need to active the feature of development to install the app. Then you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your own Application? Than you could check your webmanifest. This is wrong sometimes.

Appmanifest => Permissions => SiteCollection => Set to "Full Controll"

Comment: What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to add an app from store,
Site collection administrators can not add an app as its Sharepoint's policy for security purposes.
So you have to be a lower level from administrator to add an app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing an app that needs tenant admin permissions (say it is an app-only permission), you need to do that from central / tenant admin now.

Comment: What does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

- Reboot Your Computer.
- Check App Installer Settings in Windows.
- Free Up Disk Space on Your PC.
- Run the Installer as an Administrator.
- Check the App's 64-Bit Compatibility.
- Run Program Troubleshooters.
- Uninstall Previous Software Versions.